# jersey 2.x selectable Entityfiltering

Tags: java, json, filter, jersey, jersey-2.0

I am new in Jersey and I try to use theSelectableEntityFilteringFeature

I create a small service with the following classes/files:

a resource file called EmployeeResource.java

```
@
Path("employee")@ Produces("application/json")
public class EmployeeResource {

    @
    GET
    public Employee getEmployee() {
        System.out.println("-->Entered into getEmployee()");
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setId(123);
        employee.setName("raj");
        System.out.println(employee);
        System.out.println("<--Exited from getEmployee()");
        return employee;
    }

}
```

a domain called Employee.java

```
 @
 XmlRootElement
 public class Employee {

     private String name;

     private Integer id;

     public String getName() {
         return name;
     }

     public void setName(String name) {
         this.name = name;
     }

     public Integer getId() {
         return id;
     }

     public void setId(Integer id) {
         this.id = id;
     }

     @
     Override
     public String toString() {
         return "Employee [name=" + name + ", id=" + id + "]";
     }

 }
```

a web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.filter.jersey</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>
                        org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter,
                        org.glassfish.jersey.message.filtering.SelectableEntityFilteringFeature,
                        org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature
                    </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.entityFiltering.selectable.query</param-name>
            <param-value>select</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

a pom.xml file

```
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.howtodoinjava</groupId>
    <artifactId>SelectableFiltering</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <properties>
        <jersey2.version>2.19</jersey2.version>
        <jaxrs.version>2.0.1</jaxrs.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- JAX-RS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxrs.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Jersey 2.19 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>JerseyDemos</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The test cases are below

http://localhost:8080/SelectableFiltering/employee?select=id,name

expected response
{
   "id" : "123"
   "name": "raj"
}

http://localhost:8080/SelectableFiltering/employee?select=id

expected response
{
   "id" : "123"
}

It should return only the id but it return everything. I can't find a solution by searching the internet but maybe anybody here can tell me what i am doing wrong.

and also getting 500 as response when I accessing the above resources i.e

http://localhost:8080/SelectableFiltering/employee?select=id
http://localhost:8080/SelectableFiltering/employee?select=id,name

the stacktrace below
Jul 27, 2016 8:48:21 PM org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor aroundWriteTo
SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class com.filter.jersey.Employee, genericType=class com.filter.jersey.Employee.
Jul 27, 2016 8:48:21 PM org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFO: 1 * Server responded with a response on thread http-nio-8080-exec-12
1 < 500

here can tell me what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send JSON and HTTP Status together you can use Response as your return type.

```
    @GET
    public Response getEmployee() {
        System.out.println("-->Entered into getEmployee()");
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setId(123);
        employee.setName("Raju");
        System.out.println(employee);
        System.out.println("<--Exited from getEmployee()");

        return Response.ok(employee.toString(), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();

    }
```

Don't forget to add

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
```

Comment: I want to send json only as response my code is

@Path("employee")
@Produces("application/json")
public class EmployeeResource {
  
    @GET
    public Employee getEmployee()
    {
     System.out.println("-->Entered into getEmployee()");
         Employee employee = new Employee();
         employee.setId(123);
         employee.setName("Raju");
         System.out.println(employee);
         System.out.println("<--Exited from getEmployee()");
         return employee;
    }
 
}
but I am getting 500 error and filtering no working did I miss any thing

Comment: No, I want to return as employee as a json to client. The url is http://localhost:8080/SelectableFiltering/employee?select=id and expecting {
   "id" : "123",
} but getting  the result in the browser is Employee [name=Raju, id=123]

Comment: public String toString() {
         return "{\"id\":\""+id+"\"}";
     }

Comment: Or create a new method that handles return "{\"id\":\""+id+"\"}";

Comment: Actually My requirement is  entity-filtering like the resource @XmlRootElement
public class Address {
    private String streetAddress;
    private String region;
    private PhoneNumber phoneNumber;
} and I am trying to access the resouce http://jersey.example.com/addresses/51234?select=region,streetAddress may render only the address's region and street address properties as in the following example:
{
   "region" : "CA",
   "streetAddress" : "1234 Fake St."
}